# Can't connect to MariaDB Docker Container

Tags: mysql, docker, tcp, mariadb

I have MariaDB running on docker. Bind address is commented out in the my.cnf file and everything appears set. I know what the IP address is and am currently trying to force the TCP connection (I am using this resource: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-and-using-mariadb-via-docker/). I also have a java program in another docker container that is able to access the container - I just need to access the container myself to load some SQL. Any advice as to why it isn't connecting?

I am running this command right now (with the correct IP):

```
mysql -h 172.17.0.2 -P 3306 --protocol=TCP -u root -p
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation (soon to be fixed), misses `-p 3306:3306`  on the parameters when the container is run to expose the 3306 in the container to the host.

Recommend for next question explicitly show how the container was run, the docker inspect command used to derive your IP address, and the actual failure the `mysql` command line showed.